# WPF DataGrid Get Dirty Cell Data Without Committing

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with DataGrid for WPF. I want to get the current cell's text while editing it. The problem is you can't get the value without committing the cell first. I want to validate the text first before committing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways to do it.

The cleanest one would be to implement `IDataErrorInfo` in your model and to set `ValidatesOnDataError=true` in your bindings. (And if you don't know about `IDataErrorInfo`, I'd really encourage you to take some time to lean it because it is a VERY useful tool and is very easy to use)

Another alternative solution, which requires less code, but may be a bit less clean:

You can just add an event handler to `CellEditEnding` (or override `DataGrid.OnCellEditEnding` ) and validate the data entered before it commits. If the validation fails, you just cancel the CellEditEnding event.

Here's the code if you override `OnCellEditEnding` (which is almost exactly the same as just adding an event handler)

I took an easy example for you, here I just try to parse the text entered.
You can have access to the text entered by the user with `EditingElement` property of a `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs`

Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Try to parse the text
                double test = Double.Parse((e.EditingElement as TextBox).Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                // Mark the current editing element as invalid and cancel the event
                TextBox text = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
                BindingExpression bindingExpression =
                    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(text, TextBox.TextProperty);
                BindingExpressionBase bindingExpressionBase =
                    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(text, TextBox.TextProperty);
                ValidationError validationError =
                    new ValidationError(new ExceptionValidationRule(), bindingExpression);
                Validation.MarkInvalid(bindingExpressionBase, validationError);
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            base.OnCellEditEnding(e);
        }
```

Hope this was clear enough :)

Comment: Thanks! The alternative solution worked. But I'm also using the "OnCellEditEnding" for committing each cells immediately after transferring to another cell/when datagrid loses focus. If I use this, transferring to another cell it will not commit the last cell. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Well.. This does not seem strange to me at all: You basically want your DataGrid to prevent committing not validated text. So if you write invalid text and switch cell, the normal behavior would be to avoid commiting the invalid text, right?

Comment: So unless I've missed something, I'd say that you have the exact behavior you're looking for :)